# Creating an arcTool from Python Script - error with the output

Tags: python, arcpy, modelbuilder, pandas

I want to add this script to an ArcToolbox for a coworker, so that they can reorder a table's columns after exporting a table to excel. They are not savvy with code, so I'm trying to just provide them with a way to enter the file, and the path for the result.

I've tried to set the input as a file, and the output as a location, so that the tool will create a file at the output location using the 'Tool Properties' in ArcCataloge.
[image: right clicking the script in Catalog > Properties > navigate to Parameters tab]

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime

DY = datetime.now()
yr = DY.year
mt = DY.month

def reIndexContracts(inputFile, outFilePath):    
   df = pd.read_excel(inputFile)
   df = df.reindex(columns=['col1','col2', etc...])
   df.to_excel(r"{0}FileName{1}_{2}.xlsx".format(outFilePath,mt,yr))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reIndexContracts(arcpy.GetParameter(0),
                     arcpy.GetParameter(1))
```

Unfortunately, I get an error back that the file location does not exist, and it cites the entire path and file with the extension in the error. For example:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\the\\outpath\\FileName10_2022.xlsx"
```

What am I missing here? Hoping to just put a file and a path in, get a file out.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, what I do if I want to create an output file would be to set the output location as a DEFolder (or folder) and as input. Then the filename as a GPString (or string).

The only thing in the code that might be an issue is:

```
r"{0}FileName{1}_{2}.xlsx".format(outFilePath,mt,yr)
```

Doesn't have a slash before the FileName. Also the r shouldn't be necessary.

```
"{0}\\FileName{1}_{2}.xlsx".format(outFilePath,mt,yr)
```

I assume the FileNotFoundError is happening on to_excel and not read_excel?

You might consider instead of just GetParameter use GetParameterAsText. You can also use arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)) to make sure you are getting the values you expect to receive.

Comment: Thanks! Ill try all of these and see what happens.

Comment: Yes the error is in the "to_excel" function